# How to redirect with token after ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, authentication, redirect, bearer-token

I used .ajax to authenticate the login user from (http://localhost:8080/authentication/login) and got the token, after this, I want to redirect to the home page(http://localhost:8080/home) with the token that I had received before.

I implemented a Login function in which I used ajax to authenticate and then i tryed to use ajax again in the success of the first one to redirect to the home page.

**This is the login function**

```
var token = "";
function login(email, password){
    $.ajax({
        url: "/authentication/authenticate", 
        type:'POST', 
        data: JSON.stringify({ "email": email, "password": password }), 
        headers: {"Content-Type":"application/json"},
        success: function(result){ 
            token = result;
            alert("success "+token);
            saveAuthData(token);
            $.ajax({
                url: "/home", 
                type:'GET', 
                headers: {"Content-Type":"application/json","Authorization":"Bearer "+token},
                success: function(result){ 
                    alert("success "+result);    
                    window.location.replace("/home");                
                },
                error: function(result){ alert("error "+result);}
        });
        },
        error: function(result){ alert("error "+result.statusText);}
        });
}
```

but it just get the home page in a string type as a response, but I want to redirect the URL to http://localhost:8080/home

Answer (score 0):

If you want to redirect the user to a new page on your site using vanilla Javascript, then what you're after is this command:

```js
window.location.pathname = "/home"
```

This will reload the browser window and navigate to the current host, but with a new path. It will also retain any query string that you have used. You can use `window.location.href` to set a whole new URL, with protocol, host, port, path, and query string.

Remember that when you navigate to a new page, you can't send the `Authorization` header. That is, browsers do not set this header, so if you need to add it, then you have to use an AJAX call. Once you have the response HTML, you could try to swap it on the current page, something like: `document.getElementById("main_div").innerHTML = responseBody`.

You might want to have a look at some of the javascript frameworks, as they usually have solutions in place for these kind of behaviours that you want to implement.

Comment: Thank you so much, I wanted to redirect to another url which required Authorization but I didn't found any way to do this, so I used one url that give me the pages and the other requests that requires authentication I send them in the backend using java.

Comment: Hy @yousefahmed, i have some issue like yours, if u dont mind can you update di answer how u make it morks? tthankyou